# MySQL query: uses previous values from the table, when previous value exists. Needs to be fixed when there are still no previous values in the table

Tags: mysql, insert

```
$query = "INSERT INTO temperature (city, change, curr_temp) SELECT  city, '".$cleaned_change."',  curr_temp+'".$cleaned_change."' FROM temperature where city='".$chosen_city."' order by Time desc, id desc limit 1";
```

So, each row displays city, changes of temperature and current temperature. If we have $cleaned_change=2 (Forengheits) change for San Francisco and its curr_temp was 47F (taken from the previous row using SELECT), we insert ('San Francisco', '2', '49'). (was 47F, change is +2F, now it is 49F).

**The problem is:**
if that's the first row it doesn't work, because we have no 47F to be selected (there are no previous values). As result, it doesn't insert a row. How to fix it?

The good idea is to insert the very first row "manually" (with a temperature of 0F or 32F or whatever). And that works fine. but is there any possible way to check if curr_temp has a previous value? I want it work from the scratch (when the table is truncated, it stops working) and using just one query.

P.S. There are NO nulls. If row exists, curr_temp has a numeric value in the Table.
Thank you.

P.S.S. I forgot to notice that I have slightly simplified the query. Yes, it cleans the POST values from possible injections. But, thank you for saying that.

Comment: Hint (not connected to the question): Consider to study about SQL Injection.

Comment: Thank you. I added information to the question about that as P.S.S.

Answer (score 0):

Try making just a SELECT query, then do your PHP logic, then use an INSERT query. Then you can build in protection against SQL injection and have a simpler time with your logic.

Comment: Is it possible to use only 1 query? Thank you.